# Auto broadcasting in Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, array-broadcasting

I have two `np.ndarray`s, `data` with shape `(8000, 500)` and `sample` with shape `(1, 500)`.

What I am trying to achieve is measure various types of metrics between every row in `data` to `sample`.

When using `from sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_distances` I was able to take advantage of `numpy`'s broadcasting executing the following line

```
x = cosine_distances(data, sample)
```

But when I tried to use the same procedure with `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` I got the error

> ValueError: Input vector should be 1-D.

I guess this is a broadcasting issue and I'm trying to find a way to get around it.

My ultimate goal is to iterate over all of the distances available in `scipy.spatial.distance` that can accept two vectors and apply them to the data and the sample.

How can I replicate the broadcasting that automatically happens in `sklearn`'s in my `scipy` version of the code?

Comment: try `x = cosine_distances(data, sample.reshape((500,)))`

Comment: Tell us more about what the respective functions accept as arguments?  They must explain when they accept 2d arrays vs 1d etc.  You might even look at their source code to see how they check and massage the inputs.  I could look up that information as well, but I'm too lazy. :)

Comment: @PaulH didn't work :/

Comment: @hpaulj most of the `scipy.spatial.distance` function accept two 1-D arrays, what I'm trying to find is a way to replicate the broadcasting that happens in the `sklearn` version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, looking at the docs, http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_distances.html

With (800,500) and (1,500) inputs (`(samples, features)`), you should get back a (800,1) result (`(samples1, samples2)`).

I wouldn't describe that as broadcasting.  It's more like `dot` product, that performs some sort calculation (`norm`) over features (the 500 shape), reducing that down to one value.  It's more like `np.dot(data, sample.T)` in its handling of dimensions.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html  is `Computes the Cosine distance between 1-D arrays`, more like

```
for row in data:
   for s in sample:
      d = cosine(row, s)
```

or since `sample` has only one row

```
distances = np.array([cosine(row, sample[0]) for row in data])
```

In other words, the `sklearn` version does the pairwise iteration (maybe in compiled code), while the `spartial` just evaluates the distance for one pair.

`pairwise.cosine_similarity` does

```
 # K(X, Y) = <X, Y> / (||X||*||Y||)
 K = safe_sparse_dot(X_normalized, Y_normalized.T, dense_output=dense_output)
```

That's the `dot` like behavior that I mentioned earlier, but with the normalization added.

Comment: From what I understand (not looking at the code but at the results) is that the (1,500) gets "duplicated to a (8000,500) and then the function is made row wise. Isn't that whats going on ?

Comment: I just took as `sample` the first row of `data` and sorted the `data` by the result of the `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_distance` - and I got as the first result, the very same `sample` - that's why I see it as a row wise operation